# How to prevent converting 0.00 to 0.0 by prettier eslint automatically

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I have a ComponentA and have a requirement to put value to 0.00 by default. However, the prettier eslint will convert it from 0.00 to 0.0 when formatting this component file. How do we prevent this?

```
export const ComponentA = ({ validate, isRequired }) => (
  <ComponentB
    validate={validate}
    required={isRequired}
    value={0.00}
  />
);
```

Below are settings in .eslintrc file

```
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "prettier", "jsx-a11y", "import"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ],
```

Comment: `value={"0.00"}`. Numbers have canonical form, and `0.00` is non-canonical form of the number `0.0`. The default conversion of a number to a string will always use the canonical form. The only way to display a non-canonical form is to convert to string yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `// prettier-ignore` like this:

```
// prettier-ignore
value={0.00}
```

If it doesn't work, add `// eslint-disable-line` like this:

```
// prettier-ignore
value={0.00} // eslint-disable-line
```

In order to display them properly, you can use:

```
<div>
    value: {(Math.round(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)}
</div>
```